# How to repeat "if" statement when output is false

Tags: java, if-statement, repeat

I am working on a simple game in which the user has to guess a random number. I have all the code set up except for that fact that if the guess is too high or too low I don't know how to allow them to re-enter a number and keep playing until they get it. It just stops; here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

        System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if (number == random) {
            System.out.println("Good!");
        } else if (number > random) {
            System.out.println("Too Big");
        } else if (number < random) {
            System.out.println("Too Small");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to repeat anything you need a loop.

A common way of repeating until a condition in the middle of loop's body is satisfied is building an *infinite loop*, and adding a way to break out of it.

Idiomatic way of making an infinite loop in Java is `while(true)`:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if (number == random) {
        System.out.println("Good!");
        break; // This ends the loop
    } else if (number > random) {
        System.out.println("Too Big");
    } else if (number < random) {
        System.out.println("Too Small");
    }
}
```

This loop will continue its iterations until the code path reaches the `break` statement.

Comment: Just curious: why teach a beginner to use break when break should seldom be used and is never necessary?

Comment: @BenKnoble I disagree with your assessment of usefulness of `break`: although it can be abused like most language constructs, it also helps improve clarity in several important situations. Ending a loop from the middle of loop's body, which is common to all imperative languages, is one such situation. It is so fundamental that some languages (e.g. Ada) have loop constructs that *require* the use of a `break`-like statement (`exit` statement in Ada).

Comment: Interesting. For me, ending the body of a loop in the middle suggests a return statement, which in turn suggests that the loop is the main body of the method, although a few lines might be necessary to set up some variables. Your take is enlightening, however.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) for that. The code should work like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

        System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        boolean found = false;
        while (!found) {
           if (number == random) {
                System.out.println("Good!");
               found = true;
            } else if (number > random) {
                System.out.println("Too Big, try again:");
                number = input.nextInt();
            } else if (number < random) {
                System.out.println("Too Small, try again:");
                number = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `do...while`.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
do {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
  int number = input.nextInt();

  if (number == random) {
    System.out.println("Good!");
  } else if (number > random) {
    System.out.println("Too Big");
  } else if (number < random) {
    System.out.println("Too Small");
  }

} while ( number != random );
```

Comment: `number` is defined inside the loop which means if you use it outside the loop in the conditional statement, it is out of scope.

Comment: @brandaemon. No it won't, the random number is generated before the loop. Your point is valid about scope, the initiation of the variable could be placed outside and assigned inside if necessary.

Comment: Okay.  I get a compilation error for defining the `int` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the if statements within a do-while loop, that will loop around while the user hasn't guessed the number:

```
 int number;
 do {
    System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
    number = input.nextInt();

    if (number == random) {
        System.out.println("Good!");
    } else if (number > random) {
        System.out.println("Too Big");
    } else if (number < random) {
        System.out.println("Too Small");
    }
 } while (number != random);
```

Comment: Be aware that `number` is out of scope in this example and will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Several techniques exist to loop your request, among them:

- `while (<condition>) { <do something> }`
- `do { <something> } while (<condition>);`
- `for (<init statement>, <condition>, <update statement>) { <do something> }`

To show off, you can avoid using one of the above explicit loop constructs by using recursion:

```
mport java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void ask(int random) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if (number == random) {
            System.out.println("Good!");
        } else if (number > random) {
            System.out.println("Too Big");
            ask(random);
        } else if (number < random) {
            System.out.println("Too Small");
            ask(random);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        ask(random);
    }
}
```

Here the `ask()` method keeps calling itself, until the end condition (user guessed right) is reached.

Depending on the cleverness of the Java virtual machine this might stress the call stack, or not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to repeat code conditionally, use a loop.

```
// this code will execute only once
System.out.print("Pick a number 1-10: ");
// initialize number to a value that would not be used and not equal random
int number = -1;

// the code inside the curly braces will repeat until number == random
while (number != random) {
    // get next number
    number = input.nextInt();
    // handle case one
    if(number > random) System.out.println("Too Big");
    // handle case two
    if(number < random) System.out.println("Too Small");
}
// once number == random, the condition is false so we break out of the loop
System.out.println("Good!");
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for are constructs in the programming language that allow you do a specific thing again and again.

This is done using loops.
Check the [docs for the while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for instance. That's what you need.